add custom keyboard shortcut in Ubuntu 22.04
I want to add a custom shortcut to Fn+F4 to start a custom script I created.
Before 22.04 it was in Settings -> Keyboard & Mouse -> Custom Shortcuts
but that option is gone.
I tried
apt install gnome-tweaks

but here in the settings, I only find "Additional Layout Options" on the "Keyboard & Mouse" tab (in German: "Tastatur und Maus"->"Zusätzliche Belegungsoptionen")
There is no option either to add a new shortcut
How do I set a new custom shortcut in Ubuntu 22.04 via GUI(I don't use Wayland, I use xorg)?

The setting is still there but not visible, if you open the Settings dialog
You have to scroll down, at the bottom underneath "System"; "Texteingabe" there is the option in German.
